# Storyboard animation is not in sync with the previous animation

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am trying to implement MiddleClickScrolling in `ScrollViewer` and it works well.

The problem is when moving the pointer the `Storyboard` will restart to update the speed but when we move the pointer a jitter is occurring. I have attached a gif but **you may not notice this jitter in this gif.**

[image]

Since this a big class, I can't put all the code here. You can see my **full code on [GitHub](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/MiddleClickScrollingHelper/blob/SmoothScroll/MiddleClickScrollingHelper/MiddleClickScrolling.cs)** (**Note:** Please select SmoothScroll branch if you are cloning it). An easy way to reproduce this issue is to move the pointer Up and Down for a small distance rapidly.

This is my code for storyboard animation

```
_verticalDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
{
    EnableDependentAnimation = true,
    Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
};

//Different function
var offsetX = _currentPosition.X - _startPosition.X;
var offsetY = _currentPosition.Y - _startPosition.Y;

SetCursorType(offsetX, offsetY);

if (CanScrollVertical())
{
    if (Math.Abs(offsetY) > _threshold)
    {
        RunInUIThread(() =>
        {
            _verticalDoubleAnimation.From = _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
            _verticalDoubleAnimation.To = _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset + (offsetY > 0 ? _scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight : -_scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight);

            if ((_scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight / (Math.Abs(offsetY) * _factor)) == double.NaN)
            {
                return;
            }

            _verticalDoubleAnimation.Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight / (Math.Abs(offsetY) * _factor));
            _verticalStoryboard.Begin();
        });
    }
    else
    {
        RunInUIThread(() =>
        {
            _verticalStoryboard.Stop();
            _sliderVertical.Value = _scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of animating it, use a timer or a while loop to dynamically update the position using the ScrollViewer.ChangeView() method.  Make sure the interval is less than 16.6ms for smooth 60fps motion.  Also make sure to set the final parameter of ChangeView to false so that its built-in animation is disabled.

So in your first commit, change this:

```
timer = new Timer(ScrollAsync, null, 50, 50);
```

To this:

```
timer = new Timer(ScrollAsync, null, 0, 5);
```

The Timer does not give precision within 1ms or even 10ms to my undestanding. Overcompensating by updating it every 1-5ms should make up for that so it's probably fine and it's what I'm using in my custom scrolling control.  A [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) is very precise but is a massive CPU hog. Another option: It's a lot of extra work, but if you want precision timing and maximum performance with minimal battery usage, you can use [Win2D](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/html/Introduction.htm)'s CanvasAnimatedControl which can be used to run code exactly once every 60th of a second.

Comment: I don't think we can use Composition API directly on ScrollViewer because I tried animating `ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset` directly but it only animates the scroll bar but it won't scroll. Anyway, I will give it a try. FYI I have given the link to [my full code](https://github.com/Vijay-Nirmal/MiddleClickScrollingHelper/blob/SmoothScroll/MiddleClickScrollingHelper/MiddleClickScrolling.cs) in my post.

Comment: Also, What is `_uIElement` in your code? If I use `_scrollViewer` then it will offset the control, it won't scroll.

Comment: I think my issue is related to the easing function. Is there is a way to set `LinearEase` for `DoubleAnimation`? By default, there is no `LinearEase`

Comment: [UIElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement) It's whatever you're targeting with your Storyboard to animate.

Comment: I glanced at your code, not sure animation is what you want at all.  I did something similar but with a gamepad thumbstick and an ItemsControl.  I just updated the value dynamically using a while loop.  Remember a frame of 60fps video is only 16.6ms.  If you're updating a UIElement's translation value at a rate faster than that you don't need to animate anything it will be smooth.  Like in middle click mode, take the distance of the cursor to the center and add that to the UIElement's Y value every 5ms or something.

Comment: I have tried that even it is not smooth. Take a look at my initial commit in the master branch. It is not smooth.

Comment: Why is your storyboard targeting a slider?

Comment: If I directly animate `ScrollViewer` then only the scrollbar is moving. I got [this method from WinRTXamlToolkit](https://github.com/xyzzer/WinRTXamlToolkit/blob/master/WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/Extensions/ScrollViewerExtensions.cs)

Comment: Never mind, I have solved this issue by setting `_scrollViewer?.ChangeView` forever 5ms. Initially, I did it for 100ms, so it causes jitter. Update your answer. I will mark as answer

Comment: Yeah I was about to comment your original commit has 50ms timer with 50ms delay.  Glad it's working now, I updated my answer.

Comment: I have marked as answer. BTW 1 ms and 10 ms makes different. I have seen the difference in practice.